# How to switch IAM roles for AWS Cognito User belonging to multiple User Pool groups?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam, aws-amplify

I have a web application built with AWS Amplify and Cognito used for authentication/authorization. Cognito User Pools is the identity provider.

Users are grouped into Cognito User Pools groups based on what permissions they should have.

I want some users to be part of multiple groups (e.g. Admin users) which should have the sum of these 
group's permissions. But since the user can only assume one role I need to be able to switch roles in the app.

I tried accomplishing this by using the `getCredentialsForIdentity`:

```
  const cognito_identity = new AWS.CognitoIdentity({ apiVersion: '2014-06-30', region: 'eu-central-1' });
  var params = {
    IdentityId: 'some_identity',
    CustomRoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::<account_id>:role/editors',
  };
  cognito_identity.getCredentialsForIdentity(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
    else     console.log(data);
  });
```

When invoking the above code it fails with 
**NotAuthorizedException: Access to Identity '`some_identity' is forbidden.**

What do I need to do to make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After including the `Logins` property in the parameters to `getCredentialsForIdentity` it worked:

```
async function switchRoles(region, identityId, roleArn, cognitoArn) {
  const user = await Auth.currentUserPoolUser();
  const cognitoidentity = new AWS.CognitoIdentity({ apiVersion: '2014-06-30', region });
  const params = {
    IdentityId: identityId,
    CustomRoleArn: roleArn,
    Logins: {
      [cognitoArn]: user
        .getSignInUserSession()
        .getIdToken()
        .getJwtToken(),
    },
  };
  return cognitoidentity
    .getCredentialsForIdentity(params)
    .promise()
    .then(data => {
      return {
        accessKeyId: data.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
        sessionToken: data.Credentials.SessionToken,
        secretAccessKey: data.Credentials.SecretKey,
        expireTime: data.Credentials.Expiration,
        expired: false,
      };
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err, err.stack);
      return null;
    });
}
```

Comment: how are you utilising the output of this so that the new JWT is what any AWS will send?